# How to add delimiter to ListBox Items without being effected by the ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemtemplate

Below you can see the View and the ViewModel. 
The result will be :" A  B  C " that the **background** of each letter is red.
I want to add an arrow between the items **BUT** I dont want the arrow to be colored by red. 
That mean it should be like this : "A --> B -- > C" that ONLY the letters will be colored by red, and the arrows **NOT**.
I can use a Converter to add the arrow on the Text propertry, but it will end up color the arrow as well.

Any Idea ?

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArray}">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{Binding}" Margin="5"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MyArray = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        MyArray.Add("A");
        MyArray.Add("B");
        MyArray.Add("C");
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this:

```
  <TextBlock Margin="5">
      <Run Background="Red" Text="{Binding}"/>
      <Run Text="->"/>
  </TextBlock>
```

Or if you really must keep it out of the data template use the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) and assign a new `Template` to the `ListBoxItem` which contains an arrow next to the `ContentPresenter` where the item template will be (this might be a good idea as you then can prevent the arrow from appeearing selected).

**Edit:** I would approach the issue with the additional arrow with a `PreviousData` binding, if it is null there is no item before it:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <!-- StackPanel because Runs can't be collapsed, you could clear their text though -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="->">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}"
                                Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Red" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: going that route you'll end with 'A -> B -> C ->', which isn't what the author asked. read the question first and then answer.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. But now I'm getting an error "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath", I've solved this by using Text="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}", any more Idea about the error ?

Comment: BTW, your solution also add to the last item the arrow, how can we prevent it ?

Comment: @EitanG The default binding mode is `TwoWay`, and to use `TwoWay` bindings you need to specify a `Path` in your binding. You can't have a blank one. To get rid of the error simply use `{Binding Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: @EitanG: `Run.Text` binds TwoWay by default, you can just set the `Binding.Mode` to `OneWay`, or make it `{Binding .}` which is the same as `{Binding Path=.}` and thus binds to the source.

Comment: @EitanG: It did not seem like you were even concerned about the arrow at the end in your question so i did not touch that. There are various ways to deal with it, and there are already several questions on it around (which might be a bit hard to find).

Comment: @Dmitry: I probably do not need to tell you that i *did* read the question, and the only thing the asker seemed concerned about was the color, so i addressed that. Unlike you i only downvote when there is actually a problem, missing bits of information can easily be added if you did not notice...

Comment: unlike me you know everything, I'm not a prodigy (I probly was at  yr age). I'm just reading the question and if in doubt try to make sense out of it.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `RelativeSource.PreviousData`. I wasn't aware of that. Although how come you're using StackPanels instead of a TextBlock/Run? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm trying to use your first answer (without PreviousData) and I get an error: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Text' property of type 'Run'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject., Why is that ?

Comment: @EitanG: You are using an outdated version of the Framework (< v4.0). In that case use a horizontal `StackPanel` and two `TextBlocks`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number of items in your collection, you can set the `AlternationCount` of your `ListBox` to a number which is higher than the number of items in your collection, then use a `DataTrigger` to determine the visibility or text of your separator items.

```
<Style x:Key="ArrowTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="->" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="0" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ListBox AlternationCount="100" ItemsSource="{Binding MyArray}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ArrowTextBlockStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" Background="Red" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Edit**

As HB pointed out in his answer, you can also base your `DataTrigger` on [RelativeSource.PreviousData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.previousdata.aspx), however that will only work if none of the items in your `ItemsSource` are `null`

Comment: @HB Because it is easy to understand. I suppose I could replace it with a `TextBlock`/`Run` the way you have, but I usually don't use Runs and wasn't sure if you could style them.

Comment: You can, they're great stuff.

Comment: Also that is kind of a hack, wouldn't you agree? (On demand i amended my answer, that method might be a bit better)

Comment: @HB I fully agree it's a hack. I see the edit to your answer - I wasn't aware there was a `RelativeSource.PreviousData` property. That would have saved me some headaches in the past, although it probably wouldn't work if I had nulls in my `ItemsSource`

Comment: Can you add null as an item to a collection though?

Comment: @HB Of course, I used to use them as separators in my menu collections. My `Template` would change based on if the binding was `{x:Null}` to draw the item as a `Separator` instead of a `MenuItem`

Comment: Interesting, i would use some well defined placeholder (as with the `NewItemPlaceholder` in certain views).

Comment: @HB The menu item collection was dynamic and changed in the ViewModels based on what was occurring, so the Views had no idea where the Separators were going to be. It didn't feel right to create a new menu item object in the collection if the item wasn't actually a menu item, so I just used `nulls`.